# Как с помощью jquery по нажатию на кнопку поменять тег с p на textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как с помощью jquery по нажатию на кнопку поменять тег с p на textarea?
и добавить айди к старому тэгу и передать новому textarea тот id?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function correct(){
    $("p").replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
    return $("<textarea>").html(oldHTML);
    });

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $("textarea").css({ "background-color": "#090" });
    });

    };
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Мой тэг</p> <button onclick="correct()" >Редактировать</button>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/wonajigi/1/edit

Comment: @Анатолийй, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. А если по теме, то здесь есть готовое расширение: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468280

Comment: @Павел Азанов уточнил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Расширение** (источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468280/1941460)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) {
        var tags = [],
            i    = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            var newElement = document.createElement(replaceWith),
                thisi      = this[i],
                thisia     = thisi.attributes;
            for (var a = thisia.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                var attrib = thisia[a];
                newElement.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
            };
            newElement.innerHTML = thisi.innerHTML;
            $(thisi).after(newElement).remove();
            tags[i - 1] = newElement;
        }
        return $(tags);
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

---

**Использование**

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnEdit').click(function() {
        $('p').replaceTagName('textarea')
    });
});
```

**Демо: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ptbK/)**

Comment: Как сделать чтобы у этого p был id="number123" и такой же айли передовался textarea?

Comment: (function($) {
    $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) 
как понимать такую запись? (function($) {}
и что за fn?

Comment: При замене тэга все атрибуты (включая id) копируются. На счет конструкции: Создается плагин. Подробнее можно прочитать в [документации](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю чего вы хотите в итоге добиться, то гляньте на аттрибут [contenteditable](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126877/). Может удастся решить проблему без адских костылей